# Build Error with Yeoman and Jade

Tags: gruntjs, pug, yeoman, bower

I followed this [page](http://thephuse.com/development/short-circuits-using-jade-templates-with-yeoman/) to setup Yeoman with Jade.

Development wise everything is working fine but when I do a build the output is broken (e.g. pathes are still pointing to bower_components and it seems usemin blocks are not parsed in general).

I guess it has something to do with the usemin task but I can't figure out what I did wrong (I went over the code over and over).

Here is my [Gruntfile.js](http://pastie.org/9590190).

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Through pure trial and error I found out that if I change usemin:html from **html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html']** to **html: ['.tmp/{,*/}*.html']** it is working as expected, but sadly I don't know to which problems I introduce myself with that (also I have the feeling that this is not the best solution).

Comment: I am having the same problem. Can you post your `Gruntfile.js`? It would really help me out. The link to your `Gruntfile.js` does not work anymore.

Comment: I guess this was the Gruntfile.js I linked to: http://pastie.org/10359416. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful. How are you referring your files in the `usemin` blocks in your jade. I have tried different combinations like `<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->`, `<!-- build:js(app) scripts/vendor.js -->` and `<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->` nothing seems to work.

Comment: Here is a pastie of my layout file: http://pastie.org/10366489.